# Param is missing or value is empty until I refresh page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

Hi guys I have really strange problem.I have events and enrollments. Every time when I want to make an enrollment for specific event Rails show me:

> Error: Param is missing or value is empty: enrollment

When I refresh the page everything is Ok.

`new` view code:

```
<%=form_for :enrollment do |f|%>
    <%= f.select(:car_id) do %>
        <% current_user.cars.each do |c| %>
            <%= content_tag(:option, c.mark, value: c.id) %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <%=f.submit :save %>
<%end%>
```

Strong params:

```
def enrollment_params
  params.require(:enrollment).permit(:car_id)
end
```

`create` method:

```
def create
  @event=Event.find(params[:id])
  @enrollment = current_user.enrollments.build(enrollment_params)
  @enrollment.save
  @event.enrollments<<@enrollment
end
```

`new` action:

```
 def new
    @enrollment=Enrollment.new
 end
```

Log:

```
Started POST "/events/39/enrollments/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-05-21 22:53:52 +0300
Processing by EnrollmentsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"b4oZl8n8ALq1fgmqweygyWDF8oc7Ew3nelvhst5SRJkza8x92VNo3fXg+/gqw+NfKVPYvJfu9LCthRBGFB0xSA==", "id"=>"39"}
  Event Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "events".* FROM "events" WHERE "events"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 39]]
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 12]]
Completed 400 Bad Request in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

Routes:

```
          Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                      Controller#Action
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                         devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                         devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                        devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                        devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                    devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)                   devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)                        devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)                        devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                          devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                                 devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                         devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                            devise/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)                                 devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                                 devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                                 devise/registrations#destroy
               user_cars GET    /users/:user_id/cars(.:format)                   cars#index
                         POST   /users/:user_id/cars(.:format)                   cars#create
            new_user_car GET    /users/:user_id/cars/new(.:format)               cars#new
           edit_user_car GET    /users/:user_id/cars/:id/edit(.:format)          cars#edit
                user_car GET    /users/:user_id/cars/:id(.:format)               cars#show
                         PATCH  /users/:user_id/cars/:id(.:format)               cars#update
                         PUT    /users/:user_id/cars/:id(.:format)               cars#update
                         DELETE /users/:user_id/cars/:id(.:format)               cars#destroy
                   users GET    /users(.:format)                                 users#index
                         POST   /users(.:format)                                 users#create
                new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                             users#new
               edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                        users#edit
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                             users#show
                         PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                             users#update
                         PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                             users#update
                         DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                             users#destroy
          event_comments GET    /events/:event_id/comments(.:format)             comments#index
                         POST   /events/:event_id/comments(.:format)             comments#create
       new_event_comment GET    /events/:event_id/comments/new(.:format)         comments#new
      edit_event_comment GET    /events/:event_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format)    comments#edit
           event_comment GET    /events/:event_id/comments/:id(.:format)         comments#show
                         PATCH  /events/:event_id/comments/:id(.:format)         comments#update
                         PUT    /events/:event_id/comments/:id(.:format)         comments#update
                         DELETE /events/:event_id/comments/:id(.:format)         comments#destroy
           event_results GET    /events/:event_id/results(.:format)              results#index
                         POST   /events/:event_id/results(.:format)              results#create
        new_event_result GET    /events/:event_id/results/new(.:format)          results#new
       edit_event_result GET    /events/:event_id/results/:id/edit(.:format)     results#edit
            event_result GET    /events/:event_id/results/:id(.:format)          results#show
                         PATCH  /events/:event_id/results/:id(.:format)          results#update
                         PUT    /events/:event_id/results/:id(.:format)          results#update
                         DELETE /events/:event_id/results/:id(.:format)          results#destroy
       event_enrollments GET    /events/:event_id/enrollments(.:format)          enrollments#index
                         POST   /events/:event_id/enrollments(.:format)          enrollments#create
    new_event_enrollment GET    /events/:event_id/enrollments/new(.:format)      enrollments#new
   edit_event_enrollment GET    /events/:event_id/enrollments/:id/edit(.:format) enrollments#edit
        event_enrollment GET    /events/:event_id/enrollments/:id(.:format)      enrollments#show
                         PATCH  /events/:event_id/enrollments/:id(.:format)      enrollments#update
                         PUT    /events/:event_id/enrollments/:id(.:format)      enrollments#update
                         DELETE /events/:event_id/enrollments/:id(.:format)      enrollments#destroy
                  events GET    /events(.:format)                                events#index
                         POST   /events(.:format)                                events#create
               new_event GET    /events/new(.:format)                            events#new
              edit_event GET    /events/:id/edit(.:format)                       events#edit
                   event GET    /events/:id(.:format)                            events#show
                         PATCH  /events/:id(.:format)                            events#update
                         PUT    /events/:id(.:format)                            events#update
                         DELETE /events/:id(.:format)                            events#destroy
                         GET    /attend/:id(.:format)                            events#attend
                         POST   /cancel/:id(.:format)                            events#cancel
                     all GET    /all(.:format)                                   users#all
                         POST   /all(.:format)                                   users#all
                myevents GET    /myevents(.:format)                              users#myevents
                         POST   /myevents(.:format)                              users#myevents
                         POST   /events/:id/comments/new(.:format)               comments#create
                         GET    /events/:id/comments(.:format)                   comments#index
                         PUT    /events/:id/comments/:id/edit(.:format)          comments#edit
                         POST   /events/:id/like(.:format)                       events#like
                         GET    /events/:id/like(.:format)                       events#like
                         POST   /events/:id/unlike(.:format)                     events#unlike
                         GET    /events/:id/unlike(.:format)                     events#unlike
                         POST   /users/:id/cars/new(.:format)                    cars#create
                         DELETE /events/:id/enrollments/:id(.:format)            enrollments#destroy
                         GET    /users/:id/usercars(.:format)                    users#usercars
                         GET    /users/:id/userevents(.:format)                  users#userevents
                         POST   /events/:id/results/new(.:format)                results#create
                         GET    /events/:id/statistics(.:format)                 results#statistics
                         GET    /events/:id/classfwd(.:format)                   results#classfwd
                         GET    /events/:id/classrwd(.:format)                   results#classrwd
                         GET    /events/:id/classawd(.:format)                   results#classawd
                         GET    /events/:id/enrollments(.:format)                enrollments#index
                         GET    /users/:id/mygallery(.:format)                   users#mygallery
                    root GET    /                                                welcome#Welcome
```

Comment: some changes to form the better way to use `form_for @enrollment` where @enrollment is a new or found record.

Comment: I tried but there is no difference ......@МалъСкрылевъ

Comment: Please show the code for your `new` action and the action logs with the error.

Comment: Sorry about this, now I edited It.Is it Okey ? @Michael Gaskill

Comment: @HristiqnVeliakov The `new` action is good.  Thank you.  Please include the full logs for the action, starting with the `Started` and ending with the `Completed` lines.  This will include the route, params, SQL executed, templates rendered, etc.

Comment: Provide error log of console

Comment: @MichaelGaskill I change it.Is it better now ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I wanted to see.  Thanks!  That leads to another question. Please also show your `config/routes.rb` file (at least for all routes for `events` and `enrollments`).

Comment: I have added it.You can check it @MichaelGaskill :)

Comment: I saw it when you added it.  I made a comment on the answer from @bkunz01 about the `match` route.  That should fix the current error with the `POST` route.

Comment: Please show the code with the link to your `new` action.

Comment: Please show the code for the page that has the button that you click to get invoke the `new` action.  I believe that you have `new` and `create` mixed up, and that page will show how you're loading the the `new` action, which is the action that's failing to find a 'POST' route.

Answer (score 0):

Your error log shows you are trying to commit a post when going to "/events/39/enrollments/new".  This route needs to be a 'get' request or it will try to post to the server without any parameters included!  Go into your config/routes file and change that from a 'post' to a 'get' route and this shouldn't happen.

Edit:  You need to include the nested attribute in your form:

```
<%= form_for([@event, @enrollment]) do |f| %>
```

You then need to define @event in your new action with the params being passed in the url to it as you do in the create action.  Using these objects instead of :enrollment should also guide it to using the right action (create) instead of posting to new.

Comment: But now I have another error No route matches [POST] "/events/39/enrollments/new"

Comment: Your form is trying to post to the wrong url.  You need to make sure your form_for posts to the create action and not the new action.  I'll update the answer

Comment: Also, remove the `match` for enrollments/new` from the `routes.rb`.  The nested resources should be sufficient to have the actions that you need with the proper HTTP verbs (e.g. `get` for `new`, `post` for `create`).  This will fix the `No route matches [POST]` error that you're seeing now.

Comment: I removed match line, but the error No route matches [POST] is still there

Comment: Did you specify the relationships between enrollments and events in your models?

Comment: Yes, enrollment belongs_to :event and event has_many :enrollments

Comment: Are there any other routes above the resource routing you're showing us?  Rails routing basically looks for the first possible matching route and uses that so if you have some matching route beforehand, it will use that route over the nested resources.

Comment: Yes this is full version ,   resources :events  do
      resources :comments
      resources :results
      resources :enrollments 
   end

Comment: Comment out all routes in your `routes.rb` file except the 3 lines for `resources :events`, `resources :enrollments`, and `end`.  This will make sure that there are no other routes interfering.  See if this works, and then uncomment blocks of routes again until the problem occurs again.

Comment: type "bundle exec rake routes" and post the output from your console up top.

Comment: Try declaring the route in your form_for like this explicitly:

form_for ([@event, @enrollment], url: { action: "create" }) do |f|

Comment: I forgot to say.The error rise up when I open the page with form.With submit button everything is ok.The problem is when I click the button which invoke the new action I see the error and when I refresh the page everything si Ok again. @MichaelGaskill

Comment: Oh, try adding @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])  to your new action.  It may not be params[:event_id] but you knwo what I mean.

Comment: I added it when you edit your 1 answer(in the beginning)  :)

Comment: Then you must not be passing the parameter in your link that takes the person to that page!  Make sure you are passing the event_id as a parameter in the "link_to" that brings you to that page.  Then make sure in your new action you instantiate the @event object  based on the param from the link.